# MongoError : Connect failed - Bitnami AWS instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mean-stack, bitnami

I am trying to connect to my AWS Bitnami MEAN instance. The code has been uploaded on the server. But on connecting to it, I am getting the following error : 
[image]

I have been following the steps given at : https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-1 to connect to the instance.
In the second aprt of it, where they are making changes for mongoDB, I did all those, but since then, I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is being refused, it seems like an authentication error. You must provide the password in your application, i.e. if you are using Mongoose in order to connect:

`var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = Mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://*USER:PASSWORD*@localhost/*DATABASE*');`

You must use your correct mongodb socket and your correct password and database name.

Best regards,
Silvio Fernández